# Using Pandas function isin()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I explain my problem to you. I have a data frame and I want to add a column (true / false). This dataframe contains the following columns: Référence, msn, description... I have another dataframe containing a reference called "AM" and other columns. The objective of filling this one column (true / false) if there is a correspondence between the two tables on the refe field.
here is my python code:

```
df["Avis BE"]=False
df[df["Référence"].isin(df1["AM"])]["Avis BE"]=True
```

I have this error message:
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:1: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Comment: Maybe this post can help you. [How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20625582/16936415)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a warning, use

```
df.loc[:, "Avis BE"] = False
df.loc[df["Référence"].isin(df1["AM"]), "Avis BE"] = True
```

Also refer pandas documentation for indexing and setting values.
it highlights this issue and suggesets better practices.
[Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html)